# Hadoop for distributed compilation

Tags: hadoop, compilation, distributed-computing

Can we use hadoop framework for distributed compilation of very large source code?
I am newbie, so correct me if i am wrong anywhere.
So if yes, How?
Is there any relevant discussion or any documentation related to this, please help me ?

Comment: What language do you want to compile?

Comment: i want to use gcc for compilation but the size of source files is very large, so i want to take the help of hadoop to distribute the compilation tasks to many computer so that compilation time could reduce.

Comment: You don't need Hadoop for this task. All you need is https://code.google.com/p/distcc and some nodes where you can run it.

Comment: i dont want to do with distcc for some reason.
Can i write mapreduce program for this?

Comment: You could compile within a `map` task and link the objects in a single (and final) `reduce` task.

Comment: @harpun .. that is fine. I thought the same. But think of compiling kernel, which we do using makefiles. So for that whatever we are doing in makefile(compilation task), we need to do that from map function. Is it possible?

Comment: You can run a system command within the `map` task. For example execute a shell script, that fetches the source code and compiles it.

Comment: @harpun... I thinking to compile kernel(which we do by running make command which in turn executes Makefiles). Make command does both compiling and linking thing. So, how can I execute compilation and linking separately (think in terms of kernel compilation)?